# Error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 "

Tags: php

I have that error

[image: Error msg]

for this php code

```
$query = "insert into question values(" . $_SESSION['testqn'] . ",$newstd,'" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['question'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optiona'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optionb'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optionc'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['optiond'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctanswer'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'," . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['marks'], ENT_QUOTES) . ")";
```

Comment: echo your $query and run directly into phpmyadmin and check what it return!!

Comment: you have to provide column names and also column-names count will be equal to input values count

Comment: When i put values like this         $query = "insert into question (testid,qnid,question,optiona,optionb,optionc,optiond,correctanswer,marks) 
,it gives me Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: provide us your table column details

Comment: This is the table which i want to insert into [table](http://imgur.com/qRw4hBE)

Answer (score 1):

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1", this error would be shown if you have mismatch in the number of table columns and number of columns you are entering in the insert query.

Say, If you have 8 columns in table and if you are trying to insert with 7 or less columns you will get this error. I can see a mismatch in your [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhlvN.jpg) columns versus the insert query

Check the query and also the columns in the table, you will be able to fix this error.

Comment: When i put values like this $query = "insert into question (testid,qnid,question,optiona,optionb,optionc,optiond,correctanswer,marks) and then the rest of the above code  ,it gives me this error " Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'  "

Comment: Error: Duplicate entry for primary key, means you are inserting duplicate values for a primary key. Try a new key, it will insert.

Comment: How to try a new key?

Comment: I mean a new value for the key